# ASP.Net Button in codebehind that calls codebehind function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I'm using Telerik RadControls, in my codebehind I have the following function, a portion of which adds buttons to the footer.

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridItemEventArgs)
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
            Dim editLink As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("EditLink"), HyperLink)
            editLink.Attributes("href") = "#"
            editLink.Attributes("onclick") = [String].Format("return ShowEditForm('{0}','{1}');", e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("ID"), e.Item.ItemIndex)
        End If

        ''Add buttons to footer of grid
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridFooterItem Then
            Dim footerItem As GridFooterItem = e.Item
            ''Creat Ticket button
            Dim btn1 As New Button()
            btn1.Text = "Create Ticket"
            btn1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            btn1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "btnCreate_Click")
            footerItem.Cells(2).Controls.Add(btn1)
            ''Show All Tickets button
            Dim btn2 As New Button()
            btn2.Text = "Show All Tickets"
            btn2.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
            btn2.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "btnAll_Click")
            footerItem.Cells(2).Controls.Add(btn2)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Along with this I have the following two functions in my codebehind that I wish to call when the buttons get clicked.

```
Protected Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("itrequest.aspx", False)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnAll_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("itall_v2.aspx", False)
End Sub
```

My problem is that these functions are not getting called in the rendered page.  What's confusing me is that when I define these button with the same attributes in markup, they work fine.  I don't understand what the difference is between defining the buttons in markup vs code behind.  Why aren't these functions getting called from the buttons that I define in the code behind?  The buttons that do work and that I have commented out in my markup for testing purposes are as follows.

```
 <%--<asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create Ticket" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show All Tickets" OnClick="btnAll_Click" />
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>--%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nandokakimoto is correct, but the syntax in VB is:

```
AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf btn1_Click
```

A strange syntax where you don't use brackets even though AddHandler appears to be a function.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Attributes.Add() function is used to add HTML attributes to elements in the page. So you are adding client side script in your code. To add a code behind event to your button, use should use the following code:

```
   btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
```

Comment: Thanks nandokakimoto and bgs264 for your help.